# Why not change tab title name in MY Page

Tags: jquery

I need to frequently change title of page and I am unable to change title of tab my page, please help me.

my code sample is here,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Practice URL</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
       var x = floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
      call(x);

    }, 3000);

);
function call(c){
  if(c%2){
    document.title = 'Salim Sodha';
  } else {
    document.title = 'Gani Sodha';
  }
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center> MY PAGE FOR BROWSER TAB TITLE CHANGE</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `}` of `$(document).ready(function(){` and have extra `)` at end of function `call` and its `Math.floor` not `flor`

try this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){ 
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  call(x);

 }, 3000);

});
function call(c){
 if(c%2){
 document.title = 'Salim Sodha';
 } else {
  document.title = 'Gani Sodha';
   }
};
```

Comment: @SalimkhanSodha happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. use `Math.floor` instead of `floor`
2. Syntax error i.e. `document-ready` handler is not closed properly.
3. Additional `);` after `call` function.

*Use*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        call(x);
    }, 3000);
});

function call(c) {
    if (c % 2) {
        document.title = 'Salim Sodha';
    } else {
        document.title = 'Gani Sodha';
    }
}
```